# how can I print directly to the printer at the client PC?

Tags: odoo

I arrived to print report directly using printers (ethernet and usb ones)  using `base_report_to_printer`. what I need now is to print directly to the printer (usb one) at the client PC

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure printer using pycups.

Step to install pycups

```
1). sudo apt-get install libcups2-dev
2). sudo pip install pycups
```

Then you need to get the cloud ip of printer and need to add printer to any of the client PC using that cloud ip.

[image]

Then you need to configure printer setting in odoo, once you installed that `base_report_to_printer` module.

This module allows users to send reports to a printer attached to the server.

It adds an optional behaviour on reports to send it directly to a printer.

- Send to Client is the default behaviour providing you a downloadable PDF
- Send to Printer prints the report on selected printer

Settings can be done `globaly`, `per user`, `per report`, `per user` and `report`.

After installing enable the "Printing / Print Operator" option under access rights to give users the ability to view the print menu.

To show all available printers for your server, use the Settings/Configuration/Printing/Update Printers from CUPS wizard.

Then go to the user profile and set the users printing action and default printer.

Comment: the problem here is that my printer (usb one) won't be attached to the server but to the client PC

Comment: yes you need to attached that printer to the client PC not to the server.

Comment: In client PC you need to add that printer normally and on server you need to add it using cups configuration (cups ip). Google can help you to get the cloud ipp of that printer.

Comment: I added my printer normally on the client PC (a windows 7 PC), and on the server (a ubuntu one) I add it using cups ...plz if you can clarify it to me I will be thankful ... see the image I added to my post